# Determine when a route enters and leaves a polygon

Tags: distance, point-in-polygon, route

I have all of the segments of a route from White Horse, YK to Miami, FL. Now I want to determine how many miles I travel in each State / Province.

I have Polygons for each State and have been able to use Ray Casting to test whether or not each Segment is in a State but is there a faster way to determine when a route enters and leaves each State without testing ever single segment? Doing each segment would require over one hundred thousand lookups.

Comment: What GIS software and version are you using?

Comment: If you neglect to test a segment, it could be one that starts within a concave polygon, leaves it, and then re-enters. Thus it all comes down to finding *efficient* ways to conduct the testing rather than trying to skip some segments.

Comment: Are you programming from scratch? Perhaps ask about geoprocessing libraries that can handle that and other tasks you need. And maybe add the "intersection" tag. And welcome to GIS.SE!

Answer (score 1):

With any GIS software, you can use the "intersect" tool that will split the geometry of your segment inside each polygon and assign them the value of the State that is crossed.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a coding project and we don’t have a GIS. Just a spatial database and some Google API’s. We can get segments of the trip but they don’t tell us what State they are in.